# How to bind a key to run a shell command in dired emacs

Tags: emacs, dired

When i use dired mode in emacs, I can run a shell command by type !xxx, But how to bind a key to run this command?
  For example, I want to press O on a file, then dired will run 'cygstart' to open this file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `shell-command` function. For example:

```
(defun ls ()
  "Lists the contents of the current directory."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command "ls"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x :") 'ls); Or whatever key you want...
```

To define a command in a single buffer, you can use `local-set-key`. In dired, you can get the name of the file at point using `dired-file-name-at-point`. So, to do exactly what you asked:

```
(defun cygstart-in-dired ()
  "Uses the cygstart command to open the file at point."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "cygstart " (dired-file-name-at-point))))
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook '(lambda () 
                              (local-set-key (kbd "O") 'cygstart-in-dired)))
```

Comment: Note: I didn't know about any of these function before answering the question. I got the name of `shell-command` by using `C-h k` on `M-!`; I got the `dired-file-name-at-point` by first guessing that it would be a `dired-` function and then using `C-h f` and tab to autocomplete the name. You can also easily figure out Emacs function names and effects like this--it is a **self-documenting** editor, after all! It's just one of the many ways it is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

```
;; this will output ls
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x :") (lambda () (interactive) (shell-command "ls")))

;; this is bonus and not directly related to the question
;; will insert the current date into active buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x :") (lambda () (interactive) (insert (shell-command-to-string "date"))))
```

The `lambda` defines an anonymous function instead. That way you do not have to define a helper function which will be bound to a key in another step.

`lambda` is the keyword, and the next parentheses pair holds your arguments, if some were needed. Rest is analoguous to any regular function definition.